# How does Burpsuite sitemap (find) this PHP file from a PortSwigger lab?

Tags: burp-suite

I am doing the PortSwigger labs and came across this one: https://portswigger.net/web-security/deserialization/exploiting/lab-deserialization-arbitrary-object-injection-in-php

The first step of the solution is:

> From the site map, notice that the website references the file /libs/CustomTemplate.php

How does Burpsuite find this file? It's not being loaded by any network requests that I can see and its only reference is in an HTML comment:

> ```
>                 <!-- TODO: Refactor once /libs/CustomTemplate.php is updated -->
> ```

Does burpsuite look for potential file names/directories in comments or something? It seems like this could easily return a lot of false positives. Or is it finding this some other way?

Comment: why would it create a lot of false positives?

Comment: It says it finds it in the sitemap, unless the article is wrong it finds it there and not in the comment. Although there are many ways to do content discovery and ways to suppress false positives. I recommend you spend some time really getting to know burp, it's the industry standard for testing web applications.

Comment: @schroeder because if a file is referenced in a comment it doesn't mean it actually exists. Maybe it's a function that's been commented out that was the only use of a library that's since been deleted. Or maybe it's a comment saying "this replaces somefile.php". Etc etc.

Comment: @wireghoul "It finds it there": where's "there"? Is there some XML file that serves as the site map I'm not seeing referenced in the HTML file? Is it somehow doing directory traversal to crawl all available files and directories?

Comment: False positives? Sure, but your scenarios do not suggest what you said, which was "a lot of false positives".

Comment: "A lot" in an aggregate sense. As in if I use this tool for a year and work on a new security audit every week, that's "a lot" of false positives. Semantics I guess.

Comment: 1) There == sitemap, it literally says so. 2) You don't appear to have used burp enough to know how burp deals with observed urls of unknown existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Burp Suite looks at comments to locate potential directories and pages, even if they do not exist.

I installed Burp Suite fresh, default config, and a fresh XAMPP on my machine and added the comment:

```
<!-- TODO: Refactor once /questions/237693/fake.php is updated -->
```

to the default `index.hmtl` page and browsed to the main page to trigger Burp's passive crawling. Nothing else. I did not create the path or the file nor did I try to navigate to that location.

This was what was added to the Burp Suite sitemap:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question "Does Burp suite look ... in comments?" - the answer is no.

As it says in the lab text you quoted, the Burp [site map](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/target/site-map) has this info.

So that makes your question about false positives redundant.

Comment: But does the text mean the site's sitemap.xml or Burp Suite's [site map](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/target/site-map)?

Comment: It's Burp's one - edited for clarity.

Comment: Right, but the question seems to stand. Did the site map get populated from the HTML comment?

Comment: Burp does parse comments for paths.